# Caching, and updating my website

Tags: caching, proxy, safari, browser-cache

I learned some good stuff about caching [here](http://palizine.plynt.com/issues/2008Jul/cache-control-attributes/). I currently use `proxy-revalidate` with `max-age`.

What if I make an important change to my website I want everyone to see, even if the max-age isn't used up? How will they see the change?

For example, in Safari the change would not take place until I forced the page to reload. Simply going to the URL again did not cause the change be retrieved.

I think the main workaround is to use `must-revalidate` instead of `proxy-revalidate`, but that's not as efficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of things at work here.

First off, it depends upon how the user's browser is caching. Remember that directives on the web are *suggestions* only. If a browser doesn't want to cache (or release a cache), it won't, no matter what you set your headers to.

Another consideration is if your page has been cached by a router or firewall, it may take time to clear the cache, regardless of the user's browser.

If you have portions of your site that need to update (say, a stock ticker, or something similar), then cache-bust (google it) the javascript/css/iframe/whatever.

Otherwise, I wouldn't worry too much about it. If you have a low-traffic website, most likely your visitors will not have the content cached. The caching is useful to reduce the load of external files after the *first* page request, not to maintain content over long periods of time.